# querySelectorAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find all oferts in the var articleFirst, but the return message in the console says that "querySelectorAll" is not a function. Why I do get that error?

This is my HTML:

```
<article class="first">     
  <div class="feature parts"> 
    <div class="oferts"> 
      <div class="heart icons"></div> 
        <h1>Build with passion</h1>  
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
var articleFirst = document.querySelectorAll("article.first");
var oferts = articleFirst.querySelectorAll(".oferts");
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: articleFirst.querySelectorAll is not a function

Comment: `articleFirst` is not what you think it is. Log it to console, and you'll see.

Comment: If you know that `articleFirst` should only be returning a single node, use `document.querySelector`, at which point you can chain with `document.querySelector('article.first').querySelectorAll('.oferts')`. As written this isn't very useful, but it could allow you to use dynamic selectors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try do do this:

```
var articleFirst = document.querySelectorAll("article.first");
console.log(articleFirst)
var oferts = articleFirst[0].querySelectorAll(".oferts");
console.log(oferts)
```

With console you can see what is happening.

Or just do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("article.first .oferts");
```

Answer (score 15):

`querySelectorAll` is a method found on Element and Document nodes in the DOM.

You are trying to call it on the return value of a call to `querySelectorAll` which returns a Node List (which is an array like object). You would need to loop over the Node List and call `querySelector` all on each node in it in turn.

Alternatively, just use a descendant combinator in your initial call to it.

```
var oferts = document.querySelectorAll("article.first .oferts");
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `document.querySelector` instead of `document.querySelectorAll` because the next query depends on a `single HTMLElement` but `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', TestCtrl);

function TestCtrl() {
  var firstArticle = document.querySelector('article.first');
  
  console.log('oferts', firstArticle.querySelectorAll('.oferts'));
}
```

```html
<article class="first">     
  <div class="feature parts"> 
    <div class="oferts"> 
      <div class="heart icons"></div> 
      <h1>Build with passion</h1>  
    </div>
  </div> 
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little verbose but you could try qselectorAll('article') then turn that nodeList into an array and pick the first index.. so something like:

```
let articleList = querySelectorAll('article'); // makes a NodeList of all article tags on the webpage

let article = Array.from(articleList);

article[0];
```